# Pandas groupby apply performing slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on a program that involves large amounts of data. I am using the python pandas module to look for errors in my data. This usually works very fast. However this current piece of code I wrote seems to be way slower than it should be and I am looking for a way to speed it up.

In order for you guys to properly test it I uploaded a rather large piece of code. You should be able to run it as is. The comments in the code should explain what I am trying to do here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Filling dataframe with data
# Just ignore this part for now, real data comes from csv files, this is an example of how it looks
TimeOfDay_options = ['Day','Evening','Night']
TypeOfCargo_options = ['Goods','Passengers']
np.random.seed(1234)
n = 10000

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['ID_number'] = np.random.randint(3, size=n)
df['TimeOfDay'] = np.random.choice(TimeOfDay_options, size=n)
df['TypeOfCargo'] = np.random.choice(TypeOfCargo_options, size=n)
df['TrackStart'] = np.random.randint(400, size=n) * 900
df['SectionStart'] = np.nan
df['SectionStop'] = np.nan

grouped_df = df.groupby(['ID_number','TimeOfDay','TypeOfCargo','TrackStart'])
for index, group in grouped_df:
    if len(group) == 1:
        df.loc[group.index,['SectionStart']] = group['TrackStart']
        df.loc[group.index,['SectionStop']] = group['TrackStart'] + 899

    if len(group) > 1:
        track_start = group.loc[group.index[0],'TrackStart']
        track_end = track_start + 899
        section_stops = np.random.randint(track_start, track_end, size=len(group))
        section_stops[-1] = track_end
        section_stops = np.sort(section_stops)
        section_starts = np.insert(section_stops, 0, track_start)

        for i,start,stop in zip(group.index,section_starts,section_stops):
            df.loc[i,['SectionStart']] = start
            df.loc[i,['SectionStop']] = stop

#%% This is what a random group looks like without errors
#Note that each section neatly starts where the previous section ended
#There are no gaps (The whole track is defined)
grouped_df.get_group((2, 'Night', 'Passengers', 323100))

#%% Introducing errors to the data
df.loc[2640,'SectionStart'] += 100
df.loc[5390,'SectionStart'] += 7

#%% This is what the same group looks like after introducing errors 
#Note that the 'SectionStop' of row 1525 is no longer similar to the 'SectionStart' of row 2640
#This track now has a gap of 100, it is not completely defined from start to end
grouped_df.get_group((2, 'Night', 'Passengers', 323100))

#%% Try to locate the errors
#This is the part of the code I need to speed up

def Full_coverage(group):
    if len(group) > 1:
        #Sort the grouped data by column 'SectionStart' from low to high

        #Updated for newer pandas version
        #group.sort('SectionStart', ascending=True, inplace=True)
        group.sort_values('SectionStart', ascending=True, inplace=True)

        #Some initial values, overwritten at the end of each loop  
        #These variables correspond to the first row of the group
        start_km = group.iloc[0,4]
        end_km = group.iloc[0,5]
        end_km_index = group.index[0]

        #Loop through all the rows in the group
        #index is the index of the row
        #i is the 'SectionStart' of the row
        #j is the 'SectionStop' of the row
        #The loop starts from the 2nd row in the group
        for index, (i, j) in group.iloc[1:,[4,5]].iterrows():

            #The start of the next row must be equal to the end of the previous row in the group
            if i != end_km: 

                #Add the faulty data to the error list
                incomplete_coverage.append(('Expected startpoint: '+str(end_km)+' (row '+str(end_km_index)+')', \
                                    'Found startpoint: '+str(i)+' (row '+str(index)+')'))                

            #Overwrite these values for the next loop
            start_km = i
            end_km = j
            end_km_index = index

    return group

#Check if the complete track is completely defined (from start to end) for each combination of:
    #'ID_number','TimeOfDay','TypeOfCargo','TrackStart'
incomplete_coverage = [] #Create empty list for storing the error messages
df_grouped = df.groupby(['ID_number','TimeOfDay','TypeOfCargo','TrackStart']).apply(lambda x: Full_coverage(x))

#Print the error list
print('\nFound incomplete coverage in the following rows:')
for i,j in incomplete_coverage:
    print(i)
    print(j)
    print() 

#%%Time the procedure -- It is very slow, taking about 6.6 seconds on my pc
%timeit df.groupby(['ID_number','TimeOfDay','TypeOfCargo','TrackStart']).apply(lambda x: Full_coverage(x))
```

Comment: Have you tried using a profiler to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: The bottleneck seems to be the apply function, even when I remove the for loop in the function it remains slow (~4.25s per loop). I am wondering if there is another way to apply the function (without the apply command). I perform some other procedures on the data in this code using the agg command. This works much faster, but I don't know if its possible to perform this check (full_coverage) using the agg command.

Comment: The bottleneck is definitely in the function you're applying. There are over 5300 distinct groups in your data. Just calling ``sort`` on 5300 groups will take several seconds. Then iterating over all the values within each of those 5300 groups will take a few more seconds. I'd suggest removing the ``for`` loop in favor of a vectorized operation – you may be able to get the runtime down to ~2-3 seconds with this strategy. If that's still too slow, then you'll need to figure out how to do this without sorting the data in each group.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem, I believe, is that your data has 5300 distinct groups. Due to this, anything slow within your function will be magnified. You could probably use a vectorized operation rather than a `for` loop in your function to save time, but a much easier way to shave off a few seconds is to `return 0` rather than `return group`. When you `return group`, pandas will actually create a new data object combining your sorted groups, which you don't appear to use. When you `return 0`, pandas will combine 5300 zeros instead, which is much faster.

For example:

```
cols = ['ID_number','TimeOfDay','TypeOfCargo','TrackStart']
groups = df.groupby(cols)
print(len(groups))
# 5353

%timeit df.groupby(cols).apply(lambda group: group)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 2.41 s per loop

%timeit df.groupby(cols).apply(lambda group: 0)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 64.3 ms per loop
```

Just combining the results you don't use is taking about 2.4 seconds; the rest of the time is actual computation in your loop which you should attempt to vectorize.

---

Edit:

With a quick additional vectorized check before the `for` loop and returning `0` instead of `group`, I got the time down to about ~2sec, which is basically the cost of sorting each group. Try this function:

```
def Full_coverage(group):
    if len(group) > 1:
        group = group.sort('SectionStart', ascending=True)

        # this condition is sufficient to find when the loop
        # will add to the list
        if np.any(group.values[1:, 4] != group.values[:-1, 5]):
            start_km = group.iloc[0,4]
            end_km = group.iloc[0,5]
            end_km_index = group.index[0]

            for index, (i, j) in group.iloc[1:,[4,5]].iterrows():
                if i != end_km:
                    incomplete_coverage.append(('Expected startpoint: '+str(end_km)+' (row '+str(end_km_index)+')', \
                                        'Found startpoint: '+str(i)+' (row '+str(index)+')'))                
                start_km = i
                end_km = j
                end_km_index = index

    return 0

cols = ['ID_number','TimeOfDay','TypeOfCargo','TrackStart']
%timeit df.groupby(cols).apply(Full_coverage)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 1.74 s per loop
```

---

Edit 2: here's an example which incorporates my suggestion to move the sort outside the groupby and to remove the unnecessary loops. Removing the loops is not much faster for the given example, but will be faster if there are a lot of incompletes:

```
def Full_coverage_new(group):
    if len(group) > 1:
        mask = group.values[1:, 4] != group.values[:-1, 5]
        if np.any(mask):
            err = ('Expected startpoint: {0} (row {1}) '
                   'Found startpoint: {2} (row {3})')
            incomplete_coverage.extend([err.format(group.iloc[i, 5],
                                                   group.index[i],
                                                   group.iloc[i + 1, 4],
                                                   group.index[i + 1])
                                        for i in np.where(mask)[0]])
    return 0

incomplete_coverage = []
cols = ['ID_number','TimeOfDay','TypeOfCargo','TrackStart']
df_s = df.sort_values(['SectionStart','SectionStop'])
df_s.groupby(cols).apply(Full_coverage_nosort)
```

Comment: Wow scratch my last comment, I deleted it. This function gets my time down from 6.6 to 1.6 sec/loop. Amazing progress! Do you think there is a way to sort the data outside of the loop? I've been testing some things, but I keep getting back erroneous results.

Comment: Yes – the groupby preserves order, so you could first sort the dataframe by ``"SectionStart"`` and then use the above function with the sort step removed. For the full sort followed by groupby, I get 0.4sec.

Comment: That is exactly what Ive been trying, and while it significantly speeds up the process, the results that are stored in the list appear to be wrong. I tried df.sort('SectionStart', ascending=True, inplace=True) before running the groupby, but the error list seems to contain 8 errors now. Clearly I only introduced two errors into the data.

Comment: Solved it, seems my random data contained some duplicate 'SectionStop' values within groups. I solved it using df.sort(['SectionStart','SectionStop'], ascending=True, inplace=True).

Comment: Hmm your second edit seems to be alot slower than my answer, running at ~510ms per loop. Also, using the iloc and index commands slows it down even further when alot of errors are found.

Answer (score 0):

I found the pandas locate commands (.loc or .iloc) were also slowing down the progress. By moving the sort out of the loop and converting the data to numpy arrays at the start of the function I got an even faster result. I am aware that the data is no longer a dataframe, but the indices returned in the list can be used to find the data in the original df.

If there is any way to speed up the process even further I would appreciate the help. What I have so far:

```
def Full_coverage(group):

    if len(group) > 1:
        group_index = group.index.values
        group = group.values

        # this condition is sufficient to find when the loop will add to the list
        if np.any(group[1:, 4] != group[:-1, 5]):
            start_km = group[0,4]
            end_km = group[0,5]
            end_km_index = group_index[0]

            for index, (i, j) in zip(group_index, group[1:,[4,5]]):

                if i != end_km:
                    incomplete_coverage.append(('Expected startpoint: '+str(end_km)+' (row '+str(end_km_index)+')', \
                                        'Found startpoint: '+str(i)+' (row '+str(index)+')'))               
                start_km = i
                end_km = j
                end_km_index = index

    return 0

incomplete_coverage = []
df.sort(['SectionStart','SectionStop'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
cols = ['ID_number','TimeOfDay','TypeOfCargo','TrackStart']
%timeit df.groupby(cols).apply(Full_coverage)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 272 ms per loop
```

Comment: With the ``np.any`` check, you could probably remove the ``for`` loop completely. That would speed things up in the case of a lot of mismatches. Otherwise, ~0.2sec for logic on ~5000 distinct groups is probably about as good as you can hope for.

Comment: Ive been trying to get rid of the loop, but I cannot seem to find any way to add a separate printline for each error, without using the loop. Do you have any ideas?