# Using pandas to find existing customers prior to 90 days

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to establish new vs existing customers in a dataframe, ‘existing’ means that they exist in the dataframe more than 90 days previous to the day of the order.. trying to find the best pandas way to do this - currently I'm masking based on the date and then looking at the series:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def is_existing(row):
    mask = (df_only_90_days['placed_at'] <= (row['placed_at'] + timedelta(-1)).date())
    return row['customer_id'] in df_only_90_days.loc[mask]['customer_id']


df_only_90_days.apply(is_existing, axis=1)
```

It's fine with a few thousand records but once I get into the millions it's too slow. Apologies, new to pandas as well. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pandas [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function based on the `customer_id` and then you can look at each group independently.

Let's say your dataframe looks like this:

```
   customer_id                  placed_at
0            1 2016-11-17 19:16:35.635774
1            2 2016-11-17 19:16:35.635774
2            3 2016-11-17 19:16:35.635774
3            4 2016-11-17 19:16:35.635774
4            5 2016-11-17 19:16:35.635774
5            5 2016-07-07 00:00:00.000000
```

Customer `5` existed 90 days prior.  But none of the other customers did.  Using `groupby` we can create a groupby object, where each group contains all rows with a certain `customer_id`.  We get one group for each unique `customer_id` in your dataframe.  When we apply functions to this groupby object, it will apply to each group.

```
 groups = df.groupby("customer_id")
```

Then we can define a function that checks a given group to see if that customer existed 90 days prior.

```
 def existedBefore(g):
    # if the difference between the max and min placed_at values is less than 90 days
     # then return False.  Otherwise, return True
     # if the group only has 1 row, then max and min are the same
     # so this check still works
     if g.placed_at.max() - g.placed_at.min() >= datetime.timedelta(90):
         return True

     return False
```

Now if we run:

```
groups.apply(existedBefore)
```

We get:

```
customer_id
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
```

So we can see that customer `5` existed previously.

The performance of this solution is going to depend on how many unique customers you have.  See this link for a more in depth look at `groupby` with `apply` performance: [Pandas groupby apply performing slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33498061/pandas-groupby-apply-performing-slow)

### Vectorized Solution

If you are just looking for all user's who have registered at least 90 days prior to today, then you can do a vectorized approach instead of relying on `apply`.

```
 import datetime
 priors = df[datetime.datetime.now() - df.placed_at >= timedelta(90)]
```

`priors` will then look like this:

```
   customer_id  placed_at
5            5 2016-07-07
```

So we see that Customer `5` existed 90 days prior to today.  Your original solution was very close to this, the issue is that `apply` is just slow for large dataframes.  [There are ways to improve that performance](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html) but this vectorized approach should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks - try to vote your answer up but I don't have enough reputation. It def works but I must have a lot of unique customers because it is pretty slow. I was doing this in a database before and how I did it was to inner join the table on itself - any records that existed pre 90 and post 90  showed up in the join. I wonder if something along those lines is possible as well?

Comment: Are you just looking at user's that existed 90 days prior to the current day?   In that case, you can do a vectorized approach pretty simply.  I originally understood the question to mean you wanted all users who had at least 2 records and there was 90 days in between those records.

Comment: No it's literally 90 days from the day of the order - also an important detail is that all I really need is the count for that day, so e.g. august first there was 30 orders from 30 customers, 21 of those are existing (ordered at least once more than 90 days ago).

Comment: Then I think the vectorized solution I posted will solve the problem.  It will give you all customer_ids that existed 90 days prior to right now.  You can then do `priors.shape[0]` to get the number of rows.  Or you can do `len(priors['customer_id'].unique())` to get the number of unique customers who have existed for more than 90 days.

Comment: Naw it's not 90 days from now, it's 90 days from the date of the placed_at of each order. I've been thinking about a way to avoid having to hit each row to do that (the real time consumer) and was thinking what if we group by all customers for a the placed_at date, e.g `df.groupby(['placed_at', 'store_id'],)['customer_id'].apply(list)` - then use mask the df 90 days back (similar to how I did it originall) expect this time there's only a few thousand rows, not a million.  Thoughts?